# Escaping '.' in helms chart yaml file

Tags: kubernetes

I need to define an env var with name contains '.' characters, and Kubenetes does not seem to like it.

```
    spec:
      containers:
        env:
        - name: "com.my.app.dir"
          value: "/myapp/subdir/"
```

I tried single quotes, double quotes, backslashes, double backslashes, and many other ways. Still cannot make it work. I wonder if anyone knows a way to escape the '.' characters. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think that isn't working?

Answer (score 3):

Kubernetes doesn't have a problem setting an environment variable with a `.`

Here's a simple spec that logs the environment by directly running the `node` executable

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: env-node
spec:
  containers:
  - image: 'node:12-slim'
    name: env-node
    command:
    - node
    - '-pe'
    - process.env
    env:
    - name: OTHER
      value: here
    - name: 'ONE_two-Three.four'
      value: 'diditwork'
```

And the environment output (with some kubernetes default vars removed for brevity)

```
{
  PATH: '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
  HOSTNAME: 'env-node',
  NODE_VERSION: '12.16.1',
  OTHER: 'here',
  'ONE_two-Three.four': 'diditwork',
  HOME: '/root'
}
```

Most shells (`sh`, `bash`, `zsh`) won't accept environment variables with a `.` in them. POSIX defines `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*` as the allowed characters in the name of an environment variable.

So running the same node process via a shell:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - image: 'node:12-slim'
    name: nodeenvtest-simple-shell
    command:
    - sh
    - '-c'
    - 'node -e "console.log(process.env)"'
    env:
    - name: 'ONE_two-Three.four'
      value: 'diditwork'
    - name: 'OTHER'
      value: 'here'
```

Results in a missing environment variable:

```
{
  NODE_VERSION: '12.16.1',
  HOSTNAME: 'env-shell',
  HOME: '/root',
  OTHER: 'here',
  PATH: '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
  PWD: '/'
}
```

If there is no shell between the container and the app running, a `.` after the first character in the environment variable should be fine.

Comment: Also note that you might not be explicitly running a shell somewhere, the container images command or entrypoint could be one.